Group admin in end-to-end encrypted group chat
I was thinking about building a simple end-to-end encrypted chat with group chat capabilities. Please keep in mind that 1) it's just an experiment to help me learn more about cryptography and 2) I'm not a security expert that knows all the cyphers out there and complex encryption schemes.
I consulted a lot of sources online on how to implement a basic E2EE using a hybrid approach with a shared key. Each time a user leaves the chat group, a new secret key should be generated and distributed so that this user doesn’t have access to the new messages anymore (“key rotation”). However, this generation (and distribution) of a new key should not be done at the server side, but a so-called “group admin” must do it (since we want end-to-end encryption).
Now comes my question: what is the difference between a regular user and a group admin (conceptually and in code)? Can I choose the group creator to be the admin? And does that person need to be always online in case a user leaves and connection with the admin is needed to create the new key?
Or is there maybe a better (but still easy) way to handle this situation (creating new key without the server knowing the key)?
Thanks in advance.

Did you try with solution like seald.io?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
